# How to extract from XML column having sequences of elements

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I have an XML column in SQL Server 2005:

```
<treatmentDetails>
      <treatmentFactor>
        <treatmentFactorName>Varieties</treatmentFactorName>
        <plot>Whole</plot>
        <levels>
          <level>Var1</level>
          <level>Var2</level>
        </levels>
      </treatmentFactor>
      <treatmentFactor>
        <treatmentFactorName>Nitrogen</treatmentFactorName>
        <plot>Whole</plot>
        <levels>
          <level>N1</level>
          <level>N2</level>
          <level>N3</level> 
        </levels>
      </treatmentFactor>
</treatmentDetails>
```

From this, I wanted to create output like this:

```
Varieties Nitrogen    
Var1      N1         
var1      N2
var1      N3
var2      N1
var2      N2
var3      N3
```

I tried with `xmlfield.query` or `.value`, but I am able to extract a single value (such as Var1) or XML tags, `<level>Var1</level>`... Any help would be of great help.

Comment: your logic is not clear. Can you explain the logic behind what you are trying here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlContent XML)

INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES(1, '<treatmentDetails>
      <treatmentFactor>
        <treatmentFactorName>Varieties</treatmentFactorName>
        <plot>Whole</plot>
        <levels>
          <level>Var1</level>
          <level>Var2</level>
        </levels>
      </treatmentFactor>
      <treatmentFactor>
        <treatmentFactorName>Nitrogen</treatmentFactorName>
        <plot>Whole</plot>
        <levels>
          <level>N1</level>
          <level>N2</level>
          <level>N3</level> 
        </levels>
      </treatmentFactor>
</treatmentDetails>')

SELECT
    Varieties = TDLevel.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    Nitrogen = TDLevel2.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(20)')
FROM
    @test
CROSS APPLY
    XmlContent.nodes('/treatmentDetails/treatmentFactor[1]/levels/level') AS Tbl(TDLevel)
CROSS APPLY
    XmlContent.nodes('/treatmentDetails/treatmentFactor[2]/levels/level') AS Tbl2(TDLevel2)
```

This would give me an output something like what you're looking for.

However: I'm not clear on whether you always have just two `<treatmentFactor>` nodes under `<treatmentDetails>` - I'm just picking the first and second subnode - this might need to be adapted a bit depending on your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps. Yes, you are right. I will have more than two <treatmentFactor> nodes. I thought I will be able to modify on my own, but I think, it won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @adp70: well then you might need to look at Roman Pekar's answer - select those specific two subnodes by using their `treatmentFactorName` value.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select
    TV.V.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    TN.N.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(20)')
from table1 as A
    outer apply Data.nodes('/treatmentDetails/treatmentFactor[treatmentFactorName = "Varieties"]/levels/level') as TV(V)
    outer apply Data.nodes('/treatmentDetails/treatmentFactor[treatmentFactorName = "Nitrogen"]/levels/level') as TN(N)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fff29/9)</kbd>**